# Xcode workspace dependencies building but not packaging

Tags: xcode, build, dependencies, workspace

I have a workspace with an app and a static lib. The lib is used in the project.

When I modify the lib and build the app, the lib is well rebuilt: cool! But if I have not modified the app, the newly built lib is not packaged within the app, it lets the old one. To have the newly built lib, I have to modify the app (I add a space and delete it)...

I have tried both ways: letting Xcode managing dependencies automatically, and explicitly added the lib in the app build phase.

So if someone has an idea!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont fully get it I am afraid... you hit 'archive' and the .a file isn't included together with the .app inside the archive?

to get the .a file included in the archive, set:
go to `build settings > your static lib > skip install` and set it to `NO`

---

after the comments:
you HAVE to touch the app to get it copied to the simulator again.. mock editing a file should help

you can maybe automate this too:
add a scripting phase to the lib's build phases and have it run `touch %PATH_TO_AN_M_FILE_FROM_THE_APP%`

Comment: Sorry, if I have been misunderstood. What I meant is : If I modify my lib within my workspace, when I run my app, the build process builds the lib ok, but doesn't ship the lib in the simulator, my modifications are not executed. I need to modify also my app for it to be run with the new lib version. Is it clearer?

Comment: No it wouldnt after hearing this. Sorry no idea

Comment: Your edit seems to be an interesting workaround, but I have no idea how to mock editing a file!!!

Comment: always add and then later remove maybe a comment or just a space or so!?

Comment: Oh! You meant manually! That's what I already do... I thought you were talking about an automatic solution.

Comment: add a scripting phase to the lib's build phases and have it run `touch %PATH_TO_AN_M_FILE_FROM_THE_APP%`

Comment: I'll try it asap, and I will tell you.

Comment: Great! I used the `touch` workaround in the pre-build action, and it works just fine! Thanks a lot!